# Does the DAO pattern spoils cohesion /SRP?

Tags: design-patterns, dao, single-responsibility-principle, cohesion

Let's use as example:

```
class AccountDAO {
    create(){..}
    read(){..}
    update(){..}
    delete() {..}
}
```

How many responsibilities are there? 1 or 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SRP shouldn't be understood in a strict manner. One object should have very few responsibilities, not "one".

Here AccountDAO is only responsible for Account persistence, so it has only one responsibility.

Comment: How should the responsability of this class be described? If I say "The AccountDAO is reponsible for Account persistance" this is 1 responsability, but if I say "The AccoundDAO is reponsible to create, read, update AND delete" these are 4.  In general, the literature says that if you need to use ANDs to describe it, it means more than one responsability. So, which level of descripcion is the correct?

Comment: You'll have this problem of "granularity" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granularity) your whole career if you work as a designer/programmer. For this specific DAO problem the "litterature" says it's better to implement all CRUD operations in one class (See http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/DataAccessObject.html). Please mark my answer as valid if you think it is.

Comment: I will mark as valid as certainly you answered it for my formulated  DAO class, but I see I missed the way I formulated the question; rather than be DAO specific, I was looking for the correct granularity way to describe responsabilities. I will formulate it in another question.

Comment: I found my same DAO question formulated here  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643547/how-to-apply-single-responsibility-principle-to-a-service-class). It was answered similar as you. In addition, the answers says that the SRP is not broken as long as the DAO is only focused on one data object.